# regex split names with special characters (dash, apostrophe)

Tags: python, regex

I have a column with names, and they are all concatenated (that is, there is no space between the first and last name). I am trying to split the first and last name, which has already been asked on this website. However here, some names have dashes `\-` or apostrophes `\'`.

```
Speed-WagonMario
CruiserPetey
SthesiaAnna
De’wayneJohn
```

I want to make sure it is catched by my regex query:

```
clean_names = re.split(r'([A-Z][a-z\']+\-[A-Z][a-z\']+|[A-Z][a-z\']+)', names)
```

It works for dashes, which happen only before an uppercase letter, but not for apostrophes.

Does anyone has an opinion on how to fix my query ? Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe that's not a regular apostrophe - if you copy the 'smart quote' and paste it into your regex (for the apostrophe), it should work. It works for me.

Comment: That's what I thought yes, because it also happened to me before with quotation marks. But this time it's was a mistake from my side. Sorry and thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine a positive lookbehind (lower-case) with a positive lookahead (uppercase). Both of the matched lookarounds are kept when they are split.

```
/           // BEGIN EXPRESSION
(?<=[a-z])  // POSITIVE LOOKBEHIND [a-z]
(?=[A-Z])   // POSITIVE LOOKAHEAD  [A-Z]
/           // END EXPRESSION
```

### Python Example

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re

def pair_to_person(pair):
  person = {}
  person['firstName'] = pair[1]
  person['lastName'] = pair[0]
  return person

def parse_name_column(column_text):
  return map(pair_to_person,
    map(lambda name: re.split(r'(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])', name),
      map(lambda x: x, column_text.strip().split('\n'))))

print_list = lambda list: print('\n'.join(map(str, list))) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
  column_text = '''
Speed-WagonMario
CruiserPetey
SthesiaAnna
De’wayneJohn
'''

  names = parse_name_column(column_text)

  print_list(names)
```

#### Output

```js
{'firstName': 'Mario', 'lastName': 'Speed-Wagon'}
{'firstName': 'Petey', 'lastName': 'Cruiser'}
{'firstName': 'Anna', 'lastName': 'Sthesia'}
{'firstName': 'John', 'lastName': 'De’wayne'}
```

### JS Example

```js
const data = `
Speed-WagonMario
CruiserPetey
SthesiaAnna
De’wayneJohn
`;

const names = data.trim().split('\n')
  .map(name => name.trim().split(/(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/))
  .map(pair => ({ firstName: pair[1], lastName: pair[0] }));

console.log(names);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Thanks,  I think I have a problem with my data because that still doesn't work. It produces the same output as mine... Could that be that the apostrophe is converted to \\' instead of \' when importing it into python ?

Comment: @krasnapolsky I will add a python example, it was easier to express it in JS... oops.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried to run my query on an online regex compiler, and it worked as well, so it might also be something else from inside my code

Comment: Found it, indeed this particular character was not catched by a previous chunk of code... thanks for your help, much appreciated